# How to access a particular node in angular UI tree?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I have just started to learn angularJS. I have a created a ui-tree to show data from backend.I have to display the details of the element on click of it. But I am facing problem with accessing a particular node(element).

Can someone describe the basics of ui-tree(not the documentation from angularjs.org) and how to access a particular node from the tree?

```js
angular.module("affiliatePortal.controllers").controller("manageProductController", ["$scope", "productService","$state","$rootScope",
function($scope, productService, $state, $rootScope) {
 $scope.data = [];
    
 productService.findAll().then(function(product) {    
                
  for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {

   var productName = {
    "id" : product[i].id,
    "title" : product[i].productType,
    "paymentType": product[i].paymentType,
    "paymentBasis": product[i].paymentBasis
   }
   $scope.data.push(productName);
     }
 });
 
}]);
```

```html
<div ui-tree>
<ol class="affiliate-list" ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="data" id="tree-root">
<li class="row" ng-repeat="node in data" ui-tree-node data-nodrag ng-   include="'partials/directives/userNode.html'"></li>
  </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example

Comment: Show Your code in a Plunker that helps to help